# How can I query or view the usage and ownerships of physical memory?

Tags: windows, windows-7, memory, task-manager

On Windows 7 and Windows 2008 SP2, how can I view who or what is using up my memory? In the task manager I can see the memory usage of user processes of me and other users, but there's always a gap between the sum of the memory of the individual processes and the actual total used memory.

I understand that several drivers need memory as well, for instance, I use a ramdisk, but it isn't visible in task manager, other than in the total memory graph. Also, it seems that a process can actually use more memory than the list of processes shows: when I killed explorer.exe, the drop in memory usage was about 1.5GB, while only 220MB was reported.

How can I query these "other" memory usages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to get this application provided by Microsoft called RAMMap.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ff700229.aspx

Comment: That's actually excellent. It gives me information right down to the lowest level and clearly shows occupied memory by drivers.